# how to store timestamp in UTC format through Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, utc

Currently I am storing timestamp according to sysdate but I want to persist timestamp in UTC format. PFB the code snippet which is in my entity class.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
    @Column(name = "CREATE_DT")
    private Date createDt = new Date();
```

How I can store the timestamp in UTC format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply change the JDBC options to your JDBC connection URL: 
These are the parameters you need to change:

> useTimezone=true
>   serverTimezone=UTC

**Example:**

```
<bean id="HB_SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <!-- Connection parameters -->
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://hostname/databaseName?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</prop>
        ...
```